# ¿Cómo acedo a la carpeta /data/data/my.package.com desde android por medio de código?

Tags: android, android-studio

Tengo este código en un método, el cual me funciona perfecto:

```
String dbFileName = helper.dateToString(new Date(), "yyyy-MM-dd-hh-mm-ss") + "_" + helper.getDeviceId().substring(0, 4);
String strSrc = "/data/data/my.package.com/databases/my_database";
String strDst = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/MY_EXTERNAL_DIR/DATABASES/" + dbFileName + ".db";

File fSrc = new File(strSrc);
File fDst = new File(strDst);

Log.d(TAG, "Src: " + strSrc);
Log.d(TAG, "Dst: " + strDst);

try{
    if(fSrc.isFile()){
        helper.copy(fSrc, fDst);
    }else{
        Log.e(TAG, "Error in the src file");
    }
}catch(IOException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Sin embargo la variable `String strSrc` me tira la siguiente advertencia:

> Do not hardcode "/data/"; use Context.getFilesDir().getPath() instead

Si cambio mi `String strSrc` por:

```
String strSrc = getApplicationContext().getFilesDir().getPath() + "/my.package.com/databases/my_database";
```

Me devuelve esto:

> /data/user/0/my.package.com/files/my.package.com/databases/

Por lo tanto mi código no funciona y no me copia nada, ¿cómo puedo cambiar mi código para que me dejé de aparecer la advertencia y me devuelva el `path` que necesito?

> /data/data/my.package.com/databases/my_database

Comment: JoriusR, deseas obtener el path para obtener una base de datos?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ¿cómo puedo cambiar mi código para que me dejé de aparecer la
>   advertencia y me devuelva el path que necesito?
>
> ```
> /data/data/my.package.com/databases/my_database
> ```

Para acceder a

**/data/data**/my.package.com/databases/my_database

necesitas permisos especiales, [Root access](http://faqsandroid.com/root/) **para escribir**.

Si no los tienes, únicamente puedes acceder a la memoria externa.