# Borrar archivo de /data/data/com.example.../files/

Tags: android

Holaaa. Hago una consulta. Tengo un programa que guarda imagenes de la siguiente manera:

```
     DBHelperPropiedades db = new DBHelperPropiedades(this);

        //Si retorna una imagen
        if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if (data == null) { //Si esta vacio
                //Display an error
                return;
            }
            try { //Agrega la imagen

                //Crea la carpeta donde se guarda la imagen, si no existe
                InputStream isImg = this.getContentResolver().openInputStream(data.getData());
                //db.IMAGES_DIR es una cadena con valor "imagenes"
                File dir = new File(this.getFilesDir(),db.IMAGES_DIR);
                dir.mkdirs();

                //Coloca el nombre a la imagen (id+random)
                String imgName=idPropiedad+"-";
                imgName+=new BigInteger(20, new SecureRandom()).toString(32);

                //Obtiene el Output para la imagen
                File imgFile = new File(dir, imgName);
                FileOutputStream osImg = new FileOutputStream(imgFile);

                //Copia la imagen
                byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
                int len;
                while ((len = isImg.read(buf)) > 0) {
                    osImg.write(buf, 0, len);
                }

                //Cierra los stream
                isImg.close();
                osImg.close();

                //Guarda la URL y la foreingKey en la base de datos
                String uriImg=imgFile.getAbsolutePath();
                if(!db.addImagen(idPropiedad, uriImg)){
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Carga en Base de datos Fallida", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                //Error
            }
```

Esto me ha funcionado muy bien hasta ahora, para guardar las imagenes, y para mostrarlas en ImageView's. Sin embargo, ahora estoy haciendo un metodo para borrarlas, y no puedo hacer que funcione...

```
public boolean rmImage(String dir){
        File imgFile = new File(dir);
        if(imgFile.exists()) {
            if (imgFile.delete()) { //Se borra la imagen. Si se hizo bien, borra de la base de datos
                DBHelperPropiedades db = new DBHelperPropiedades(this);
                db.rmImage(dir);
            } else {//Si se hizo mal
                Toast.makeText(this, "Se ha producido un error al eliminar la imagen", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
```

El problema es, que la ruta que se guarda en la base de datos, es la siguiente:
/data/data/com.example.facu.dbproperty/files/imagenes/1-mkpb3smpf7h0v

Y de acuerdo a esto 
[¿Cómo acedo a la carpeta /data/data/my.package.com desde android por medio de código?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/37108/c%c3%b3mo-acedo-a-la-carpeta-data-data-my-package-com-desde-android-por-medio-de-c%c3%b3) estaria necesitando acceso Root. Entonces, como guardar correctamente la ruta, para poder mostrarla y borrarla luego? O como borrar el archivo con la ruta que ya tengo?

Gracias abrazo!

Answer (score 2):

A usar [getFilesDir()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getFilesDir()) ciertamente estas guardando las imagenes en el almacenamiento interno.

```
File dir = new File(this.getFilesDir(), db.IMAGES_DIR);
```

Sin embargo en el método no especifica recibir este path, asegura que el valor que recibe es el correcto:

```
String pathArchivo = this.getFilesDir() + db.IMAGES_DIR + nombeArchivo;
```

y con este llamar tu método:

```
rmImage(pathArchivo);
```

---

Para eliminar un archivo dentro del la memoria interna es simplemente especificar el nombre del archivo (o directorio extra) dentro de `getFilesDir()`:

```
File dir = getFilesDir();
File file = new File(dir, "directorioextra/nombrearchivo");
boolean deleted = file.delete();
```

Comment: En realidad, el String dir que paso al rmImage, es el que he guardado en la base de datos: String uriImg=imgFile.getAbsolutePath();                                                                            if(!db.addImagen(idPropiedad, uriImg)){...  Muchas gracias por tu respuesta. Pruebo y cualquier cosa te aviso :)